# Conditional formatting with several rules Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So I want the following conditions to be achieved based on the value of an external cell:

- If the text in the external cell coincides with the one in the selected cell, the selected cell turns green. [DONE with Format Rule: Is equal to =externalCell]
- If the text in the external cell does not coincide with the one in the selected cell, the selected cell turns red. [DONE with Format Rule: Is not equal to =externalCell]
- If there is no text in the external cell, the selected cell turns white. [PENDING]

**Please see the screenshot in the link for a better understanding, where you can see my conditional format rules**.

[In this case, selected cell J10 is green because coincides with external cell T10. It would be red in any other case, but don't know how to supply the third condition.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmyhC.png)

[image: 1]

**EDIT**: Let's explain it with an example. What I want to do is that:

- (A1 will **always** have text)
- A1 turns colour white when B1 **HAS NO** text in it.
- A1 turns colour green when B1 **HAS** text in it and the text in both cells **match**.
- A1 turns colour red when B1 **HAS** text in it and the text in both cells **DO NOT match**.

Comment: its unclear what are you after. explain it more and provide some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - (A1 will always have text)
> - A1 turns colour white when B1 HAS NO text in it.
> - A1 turns colour green when B1 HAS text in it and the text in both cells match.
> - A1 turns colour red when B1 HAS text in it and the text in both cells DO NOT match.

try it like this:

[image: 0]

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted to do. The point is that (according to the example) the cell J10:M10 turns colour white when T10 is empty, with no text in it. Then, when you add some text to T10, J10:M10 turns green if the text in both match and turns red if doesn't match (those are the rules already included)

Comment: so again... whats your question?

Comment: I have just added some example to my post for better understanding